# ClassNotFoundException at asm.ObjectWriter.getCommonSuperClass

Tags: java

I'm trying to instrument the Apache Commons Math with the asm library and for some classes a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when I try to write it to a file using a ClassWriter.

One class that throws the error is `org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealVector.class`

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.linear.Array2DRowRealMatrix
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(Unknown Source)
```

I googled for the Exception and all I could find was related to some cobertura problems, or other unrelated libraries that weren't helpful.

This even happens if I don't perform any instrumentation at all. I also tried to explicitly adding the missing class to the classpath, but this didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: as per stack trace it means you are missing commons-math*jar? Do you have it and asm*.jar in your classpath?

Comment: the asm.jar is part of the jar that I use to run the instrumentation. I haven't added the commons-math as a jar, but the target/classes folder of it, after building it manually

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the ASM in your environment is loaded from the bootstrap classloder, and the math3 class for another classloader. 
When the ClassWriter calls "getCommonSuperClass" it calls "GetClass().GetClassLoader()", which will give him the bootstrap classloader.
However, it is trying to merge the frames of RealVector (which is already loaded) and Array2DRowRealMatrix, and the latter can't be found using the bootstrap classloader.

One solution is that if you're using calling the ClassWriter yourself - remove the flag that tell the writer to compute the frames.

Another solution is to try and load ASM from the system loader.